# Error: Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric
>   on below code.

```
declare @A as   nvarchar(100)   --will be Nvarchar only
    declare @T as   nvarchar(100)     --will be Nvarchar only
    declare @Act as nvarchar(100) --will be Nvarchar only
    set @A ='750000'
    set @T ='552000'

    SELECT  @Act = cast(cast(cast(@A  AS decimal(10, 4)) -cast( @T AS decimal(10, 4)) 
    /cast(@T AS decimal(10, 4)) AS decimal(10, 4)) * 100 AS numeric(10, 4))
```

How to get ride of this error?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Surely the first thing to fix is using the wrong data types all over the place. If you're wanting to do maths, why are your start and end points `nvarchar`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, there could be character in @A & @T, based on cases will do the Maths, Hence datatype selected as NVARCHAR.

Comment: @Kam I already post an answer to your question, but still is not clear what you are trying to do really, if one of the answers posted solve your issue, then please consider to upvote and accept it, if not then please edit your question to tell us exactly what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Sami, Thanks Sami!! it got cleared in 1st  comment. I was trying to give the clarification on data type only.

Comment: @Kam You consider to accept an answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why are you using the wrong datatype and make things hard for you, you should always use the proper datatype.

So instead of `VARCHAR` why don't use `DECIMAL`, still here is the query since your question is *How to get ride of this error*

```
declare @A as   nvarchar(100)   --will be Nvarchar only
    declare @T as   nvarchar(100)     --will be Nvarchar only
    declare @Act as nvarchar(100) --will be Nvarchar only
    set @A ='750000'
    set @T ='552000'


SELECT @Act = CAST(
                    (
                      CAST(@A AS DECIMAL(10,4))-
                      CAST(@T AS DECIMAL(10,4))
                    ) /
                    (CAST(@T AS DECIMAL(10,4)) * 100)
                  AS VARCHAR);
SELECT @Act
```

No need to cast `AS numeric(10, 4)` and you need to cast to `VARCHAR` since you are assign the value to a varchar variable, not a numeric one.

Your query will be easy if you change the datatypes, eg:

```
DECLARE @A DECIMAL(10,4) = 750000,
        @T DECIMAL(10,4) = 552000,
        @Act VARCHAR(100);

SELECT @Act = CAST((@A - @T) / (@T * 100) AS VARCHAR(100))

SELECT @Act
```

Or if you want to cast the result as `numeric(10, 4)`

```
DECLARE @A DECIMAL(10,4) = 750000,
        @T DECIMAL(10,4) = 552000,
        @Act VARCHAR(100);

SELECT @Act = CAST(CAST((@A - @T) / (@T * 100) AS numeric(10, 4)) AS VARCHAR(100))

SELECT @Act
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the precision value higher. 
Try to change like this:

```
declare @A as   nvarchar(100)   --will be Nvarchar only
    declare @T as   nvarchar(100)     --will be Nvarchar only
    declare @Act as nvarchar(100) --will be Nvarchar only
    set @A ='750000'
    set @T ='552000'

    SELECT  @Act = cast(cast(cast(@A  AS decimal(18, 2)) -cast( @T AS decimal(18, 4)) 
    /cast(@T AS decimal(18, 4)) AS decimal(18, 4)) * 100 AS numeric(18, 4))

    print @Act
```

Answer (score 0):

It is giving error because

> The entire length of the number you have provided is greater than ten.

You can change your code as shown below `10, 4` to `18, 4`.

```
SELECT  @Act = cast(cast(cast(@A  AS decimal(10, 4)) -cast( @T AS decimal(10, 4)) 
    /cast(@T AS decimal(10, 4)) AS decimal(18, 4)) * 100 
    AS numeric(18, 4))
```

It's value is more than the max limit so it is giving exception.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your logic correctly, what you want to do with:

```
SELECT @Act = 
    cast(
        cast(
            cast(@A  AS decimal(10, 4)) - 
            cast(@T AS decimal(10, 4)) / cast(@T AS decimal(10, 4)) 
        AS decimal(10, 4)) 
        * 100
    AS numeric(10, 4))
```

is this simple calculation:

```
SELECT @Act = (@N1 - @N2/@N2) * 100
```

Then, in your case, you need to cast `@Act` as `numeric(12, 4)`, because you multiple by 100. Your result will be: `74999900.0000`.

I'm not sure, but I think that you probably want to calculate:

```
SELECT @Act = (@N1 - @N2)/@N2 * 100
```

Even then, as a rule, always consider the range of your math calculations and use appropriate numeric data type for your variables.